# TImageList.ShareImages - How to use exactly to not have to copy the content?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I use C++ Builder, but the question is just as relevant for Delphi I believe.

When I have two `TImageList` objects and at some point I want to use the same icons in both image lists, I can copy the content: `ImageList2.Assign(ImageList1) ;`

However, I noticed `TImageList.ShareImages` in Help suggesting I can use the same internal list, and save resources copying !?  Poorly documented however because I'm not sure how I can achieve this exactly ?
What do I do to make `ImageList2` use the same internal list as `ImageList1` ?  (I would set `ImageList2.ShareImages = true` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I read the source code, you do it like this:

```
ImageList2->Handle = ImageList1->Handle;
ImageList2->ShareImages = true;
```

All that `ShareImages` controls is whether or not the image list handle is owner by the list. In this case it is owned by `ImageList1` and not by `ImageList2`.

A consequence of this is that `ImageList1` must out live `ImageList2`. Otherwise if `ImageList1` is destroyed first, then `ImageList2` is left holding on to a handle of an image list that has been destroyed.

Comment: Would there be any special precautions to be noted of if one would dynamically free one of those ImageLists?

Comment: @BlurrySterk Thank you, I have added a paragraph to that effect.

Comment: Thanks David. I understand.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan ... that simple he :)

Comment: Depending on when the ImageLists are freed, you might use the `ImageList1.FreeNotification()` method to be notified when `ImageList1` is freed so you can set `ImageList2.Handle` to 0 if `ImageList2` is still alive.